# if $f$ vanishes nowhere on $V$, then $f$ is invertible on $C[V]$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $V$ be an affine variety over $\mathbf{C}$ and let $f \in \mathbf{C}[V ]$. Show that if $f$ vanishes nowhere on $V$ then $f$ is invertible in $\mathbf[V ]$.
Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Dear Nivedita, you asked another question and I answered, what it helpful ? If it is not, you can leave a comment for the answerer to improve its answer. If it was helpful, you can leave a green check for validate the question.

Comment: Thank you so much. I found it useful and have indeed responded to the answer given.

Answer (score 4):

Let $V=\mathcal V(I)$. If $f$ vanishes nowhere on $V$, we have $\mathcal  V(I,f) = \emptyset$, i.e. the weak Nullstellensatz yields $1 \in (I,f)$. This is the same as saying that $f$ is a unit in $k[x_1, \dotsc, x_n]/I$.

Comment: Ahh! Now I understand... Thank you so much.!