# What is a function on an affine variety?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is a rather simple question but one that is bugging me. Let $V$ be a quasi-projective variety that is isomorphic to a Zariski closed subset $W$ of affine space. When we say that $f$ is a function in the coordinate ring of an affine variety $V$, should I think of this as an element of $\mathbb{C}[W]$?

I ask this because I am trying to show that if $f$ vanishes nowhere on $V$, then $f$ is invertible in its coordinate ring.

[if $f$ vanishes nowhere on $V$, then $f$ is invertible on $C[V]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2305273/if-f-vanishes-nowhere-on-v-then-f-is-invertible-on-cv)

The link shows a proof to this, but this bothers me as $V$ in its ambient space may not be a Zariski closed subset of affine space, so taking its coordinate ring directly seems odd. When the answer in the link takes the coordinate ring, is it implicitly taking the coordinate ring of $W$? So can I think of $f$ as just a function on $W$ by $f(w) = f(F(w))$ where $F$ is the isomorphism $F: W \rightarrow V$?

Comment: A good answer depends on your definition of an affine variety - can you add your definition to the question so potential answerers can more directly address your confusion?

Comment: If $f$ is not invertible then $(f)$ is a proper ideal, it is contained in a maximal ideal which is a zero of $f$ (the maximal ideals are intrinsic, you need $V$ to be affine (ie. isomorphic to an affine algebraic set) to make sure this maximal ideal corresponds to a point of $V$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is that coordinate algebras are intrinsic - they don't depend upon the embedding of our variety in to a bigger space. Therefore it doesn't matter where our variety is embedded: every way to compute the coordinate algebra will give us isomorphic answers. So your final line about viewing $f$ as a function on $W$ via the pullback is fine. (As you spend more time in algebraic geometry, this potential gap in your understanding should disappear for definitional reasons: the objects that track what "functions" are on a variety or their generalizations become part of the data of the object, and they always play nice with embeddings.)